# How to use JMAP with Tomcat when Tomcat is running as a service?

Tags: windows-server-2008, tomcat, java

I want to grab some memory snapshots of a Tomcat instance in production.  This is on a Windows 2008 server.   I can run JMAP against Tomcat when I start it with startup.bat but the client is using Tomcat as a service (tomcat6.exe).   When I try to connect to that PID I get "5868: Not enough storage is available to process this command".

Any ideas on how to get JMAP to recognize the Java process under tomcat6.exe?

Comment: It seems that this thread may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/906620/jstack-and-not-enough-storage-is-available-to-process-this-command/1677263